# ALM Java API : Creation of Child Iterations

Tags: java, rational-team-concert

I have to extend a child iteration for several timelines. With the help of understanding and using the rtc java client api I was able to get the right parent iteration. Creating a new Iteration in general was also not an issue but now I struggle in adding this iteration as child. Here's the my actual code:

```
IIteration planIteration = deveLineHelper
                                 .findIteration(owningProcessArea.getProjectArea(), 
                                                path, DevelopmentLineHelper.BYLABEL);
 

IIteration newIter = (IIteration) IIteration.ITEM_TYPE.createItem();
        newIter.setName("iterationName");
        newIter.setId("iterationID");
        newIter.setStartDate(new Date(YYYY, MM, DD, HH, MM, SS));
        newIter.setEndDate(new Date(YYYY, MM, DD, HH, MM, SS));

        newIter.setParent(planIteration);
        planIteration.addChild(newIter);
```

Set parent went fine so far but when adding the child it always failed with the exception:
**com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.addChild(Unknown Source)**

But as per the Iteration Documentation I have to do the linking from both sides.

Do you have an Idea what went wrong here?

Comment: Did some more research. Not sure if that goes into the right direction but the exception starts with:
com.ibm.team.repository.common.internal.ImmutablePropertyException

Might it be that I need a workingCopy?
If so, how to get a workingCopy?